# Sending integer value using DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, android

I am using `DefaultHttpClient` to send data to web...  To send data m using following code block:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

but namevaluepairs only take string.. I need to send integer value with this.

Please guide.. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Integer.toString(integerValue)`. For example:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, Integer.toString(5)));
```

**Edit, further to the comments below**:
And for a float you can use:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, Float.toString(10.82522f)));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply... I tried this earlier but in case of values like 10.84522 it converts to  1084522   so please suggest how to resolve this issue...

Comment: This is because 10.84522 is not an integer but a floating point value. Use Float.toString(10.84522). (Anyway, Integer.toString() does not convert 5.5 to 55, you must have done something else)

Comment: check which locake you are running in.. for example with german locale 125.25 == 12,525 and 125,25 == 125.25.. the , and the . are interchanged in that locale.. this was just an example you need to figure out which locale your jvm is running in.

Comment: it seams like "culture problem" on server side :) ... in many countries "." it's decimal separator ... but sometimes it's thousand separator ... many programming languages using local culture setting to parse numbers/dates/etc. ...

Comment: What I meant above is that `String str = Integer.toString(5.55);` does not even compile: "The method toString(int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (double)"